# Programmatical differences and practices between ImageIndex, ImageKey, and StateImageIndex in ListView?

Tags: c#

I have a Listview linked to an imagelist with Small ImageList. I notice that when applying one of those said images with ImageIndex and ImageKey, it does the same thing and changes the image in the item. What is the difference between these 3? Are certain ones used differently for certain programming design and practices?

Comment: Read the doco..

Comment: I did, but "Gets or sets the index of the image that is displayed for the item." and "Gets or sets the key for the image that is displayed for the item." is not that descriptive. Care to elaborate what you guys as programmers use either for? Which one do you use by default, etc.

Comment: You can select an image for the listview item with either a string or a number.  Thus ImageKey and ImageIndex.  StateImageIndex is useful if you want to replace the checkbox, only relevant if the ListView.CheckBoxes is set to true.